# Vue.js slow compiling

Tags: performance, compilation, vue.js

`npm run dev` executes very fast.

When I add 1000 rows of html (header) to a .vue file (template), it takes 9 minutes to compile.

Question:

Does vue.js not support such a lengthy template?

Is there any way to speed up?

```
<template>
  <header class="..." >
    ... (1000 rows)
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Header'
}
</script>
```

Comment: The question being?

Comment: @Vivick Thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: use a `v-for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a static template with static 1000 html elements. Use **v-for**!
What it will do is just compile (not run!) the Vue syntax on `<template>`.
Check this out as well: [One Useful Link on Rows Rendering on Different Frameworks](http://stefankrause.net/js-frameworks-benchmark4/webdriver-ts/table.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by prettier eslint.

**Solution**

Follow this steps to fix it.

1. goto /node_modules/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler/index.js lines 78:81
2. Change

```
    if (!isProduction) {

      code = prettier.format(code, { semi: false })

    }
```

to

```
    // if (!isProduction) { 

      // code = prettier.format(code, { semi: false })

    // }
```